# How can I find $P(X>Y)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

both X and Y values are between 0 and 1.

$f(x,y) = c(x+y)$

I am looking for $P(X>Y)$ but I'm not quite understanding how to calculate the integral limits.

Should it be

$P(X-Y>0)=\int_0^1 \int_0^x{c(x+y) dy} dx$

if so, why was the outer integral from 0 to 1 and not x to 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are integrating this area, and can be interpreted as

$$
D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:0\le x\le 1, 0\le y \le x\}.
$$

[image]

If outer integral is from $0$ to $1$, then you integrate on rectangle $[0,1]\times [0,1]$.

The integral you set is equivalent to
$$
\int_0^1 \int_y^1 c(x+y)dxdy.\text{ (why?)}
$$

Comment: that makes so much more sense. Thank u! and it is equivalent if you integrate x before y. If we are to assume that each value represents a range of like for a product from 0 to 1 for two people. and the answer to the integral above is c/2, does this tell us that the variables are independent? And is it correct to assume that one likes the product twice as much?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ seems to be random variables, then what we can conclude is that the probability that one likes the product much more is $\frac{c}{2}$, (You can find $c$ because $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 c(x+y)dxdy=1$ by property of PDF) not that one likes the product twice as much. And to show that variables are independent, you have to show that $f(x,y)=f_X(x) f_Y(y)$, where $f_X$ and $f_Y$ are marginal PDF of $X$ and $Y$ respectively.